# Cannot make intersection between two nested arrays

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm making translations dynamic, but I'm struggling in the part when I have to show the corresponding object from the other array.

I have two arrays, which have the same model, and what I'm trying to do is, when I search for a translation, I want to show also the corresponding translation from the other language.

For the moment, I can only show the one that you are searching for.

For example: If I search for the sentence *Are you sure?*, besides the *Are you sure?* sentence, it should show also the corresponding sentence from the other column language.

Here is a snippet with an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-smoke-n6w6i?file=/src/App.js

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: internationalisation is not an easy task. eventually you'll run into complex issues such as correctly handling plurals for languages that might have more than 2 plural forms. use some i18n library, one example is [formatJS](https://formatjs.io/).

Comment: @szaman, thanks for your reply! Yes, I'm using the react-i18next library, but this is not for that, it is only for our resources, we want to manage those from the admin panel. So, all the localizations we fetch from the backend, we don't have files saved in react app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic is to filter the selected language items by their **id**, not by their **value**. The `id` is taken from the default language items.

This is how

```
const searchByresourceId = (targetLng, selectedResources) => {
  // get the default language item id
  const ids = selectedResources.map(({languageResources}) => languageResources.map(({id}) => id)).flat();

  return targetLng
    ?.map((item) => {
      const languageResources = item.languageResources.filter(
        (namespace) =>
          ids.includes(namespace.id)
      );
      return {
        ...item,
        languageResources
      };
    })
    .filter((item) => item.languageResources.length > 0);
}
```

Ans you should change how you set the state

```
const searchByresourceId = (targetLng, selectedResources) => {
  const ids = selectedResources.map(({languageResources}) => languageResources.map(({id}) => id)).flat();
  return targetLng
    ?.map((item) => {
      const languageResources = item.languageResources.filter(
        (namespace) =>
          ids.includes(namespace.id)
      );
      return {
        ...item,
        languageResources
      };
    })
    .filter((item) => item.languageResources.length > 0);
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-ellis-ccdhx?file=/src/App.js

The code is not optimized of course, I just demonstrated the logic

Comment: Thank u a lot for your effort! This is what I'm looking for, but there is another problem, cuz, at this moment you can search only in English, what should I do when I have to search for the other language as well? How can I bring both of them together somehow? @mosh

Comment: The logic I can think of is to separate the "searching" part from the "viewing" part. "Searching part" - search the term in all the resources and get the ids. "Viewing" part (2) filter both default and selected language resources  by the id's list. You can try implement it. I'll try to dedicate some time if you need more help with that

Comment: I followed up your idea and it works!! Thank you a lot! I really appreciate it :). I've joined the two arrays into a single one, and I added an attribute default, in order to know which one is for default and for selected. Can you please check: https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-meadow-ommxp?file=/src/App.js? @mosh what do you think?

Comment: Glad to hear :) I wonder however if it works as expected. If I type `A je i sigurt?` I can see only one item in the right list. Is that ok?

Comment: Lol, for some reason I forgot to save the snippet, check it out now :) @mosh

Comment: :) Yes, something like this (the code can be prettier and shorter but the principal is what I meant. I'd also change `searchByresourceId = (targetLng, selectedResources)` to `searchByresourceId = (languages, selectedResources)` because this argument is not loner the target language.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'll refactor it, I just wanted to make a solution first. Thank u a lot! Much appreciate it! :)

Comment: Sure, no problem :)